# Unexpected NaN values in Pandas when trying to assign between dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data sets: the first is named 'X' and has 8 columns, the second is named 'bayers_p' and has one column. Both have length  4152 rows and I want to put column 'bayers_p' into 'X'. It is important to mention that column 'bayers_p' contains the integer values 0,1,2. In order to do this I try with this lines of code:

```
type(X),type(bayers_p)
(pandas.core.frame.DataFrame, pandas.core.frame.DataFrame)

 bayers_p['Column'].unique()
 array([2, 1, 0], dtype=int64)

 x.shape,bayers_p['Column'].shape
((4152,), (4152,))

bayers_f = X.assign(bayers_p=bayers_p['Column'])
```

But unfortunately when I execute last line of code I can only see in last column NaN values. So can anybody help me how to solve that?

Comment: Can you check the types of your columns?

Comment: **You're trying to assign between dataframes with incompatible indices, which will give NaNs** wherever df2 didn't have an element for that index value. You want to acess the values, but ignore the index entirely, similar to how `.iloc[]` does.

Comment: And avoiding having any NaNs will prevent 'bayers_p' column dtype being 'promoted' from integer to float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tries to match the index too, so it fails. You can try to set it with the underlying values:

```
# assign over the underlying numpy array
bayers_f = X.assign(bayers_p=bayers_p["Column"].to_numpy())
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably an error with indeces, because dataframe sizes match. Try this:

```py
X.reset_index().assign(bayers_p=bayers_p['Column'].reset_index())
```